Homology groups of the non orientable genus g surface
I've been asked to compute the homology groups of $\Sigma_g^-$, the non-orientable genus g surface defined by the following $2g$-gon. To do so, I've thought of the surface as a CW-complex with $1$ $0$-cell, $g$ $1$-cells with attaching map $a_1a_1a_2a_2\cdots a_ga_g$ and $1$ $2$-cell, so the chain complex of this surface should be
$$
0 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} 
\overset{d_2}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{Z}^{g} 
\overset{d_1}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{Z} 
\overset{0}{\longrightarrow} 0 
$$
Now, all that's left is to compute $d_1$ and $d_2$. As we just have one $0$-cell, $d_1=0$. Now, to compute $d_2$, we can use that this map is the sum of the degree of the maps
$$
f_{ij}: (S^1)_i^{\strut} \longrightarrow \bigvee_g\! S^1 \longrightarrow \bigvee_g\! S^1 \mathbin{\Bigm/} \bigl(\,\bigvee_g\! S^1 \setminus e_j\bigr) \longrightarrow S^1 
$$
If my understanding is not flawed (which is probably the case, but nvm), what this map does is: firstly, attach $S^1$ along a wedge sum of $g$ $S^1$ following the attaching map (this is, by going 2 times around each loop, as the attaching word is $a_1a_1a_2a_2\cdots$). Then, it gets rid of everything that is not on the $e_j$-cell (i.e., contract every $S^1$ to a point, except the one that was travelled along in the $j$-th place).
Thus, each of these maps would map 1 to 2, sure? And thus, $d_2 = \sum_{g} 2 = 2g$. This would lead to the (incorrect) conclusion that $H_1(\Sigma_g^-) = \mathbb{Z}^{2g} / 2g \mathbb{Z}$, but I can't understand what I've done wrongly. Can someone help?

Your chain complex is wrong to begin with. See also here.
